# CMake get sources files list in parent directory

Tags: file, cmake

I have a project which is organized like this:

```
<path_to_project>
  |_ build
  |_ exe1
  | |_ src
  | |_ includes
  |_ exe2
  | |_ src
  | |_ includes
  |_ libs
    |_ src
    |_ includes
```

I want to manage all different compilation parts of it with CMake (I'm new to it).

For this I created a `CMakeLists.txt` at the root directory, in it I added the line:
 `add_executable(exe1 ${EXE1_SOURCES})`

Where `EXE1_SOURCES` is defined, in a `CMakeLists.txt` in the `exe1/src` directory, with all `exe1` sources files.

When I go in the `build` directory, and I make `cmake ..`, it says `add_executable called with incorrect number of arguments`, which means it cannot find the `EXE1_SOURCES` variable.

I tried two things:

- Add `CACHE INTERNAL` at the end of the set command
- Add `PARENT_SCOPE` at then end of the set command, and add `exe1/MakeLists.txt` and write `set(EXE1_SOURCES ${EXE1_SOURCES} PARENT_SCOPE)`

But both failed.

What is the simplest way to achieve what I want to do ?

Comment: Did you add the `exe1/src`-directory as a subdirectory to the parent `CMakeLists.txt`?

Comment: Now I do, and it works fine. Thanks

Comment: You should add that as an answer so that other people may benefit if they have this same question ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to make all variable defined in a subdirectory `CMakeLists.txt`, I had to add `add_subdirectory(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/exe1/src)` in the main `CMakeLists.txt`.